# Modal suggestion/tips for an AJAX submit

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-ui

This isn't as much a code question as I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

I have a submit which currently pops up an animated gif on submit of the page (the write to the database takes a few seconds and so I use this to let the user know the site isn't frozen).  What I'd like though is for that animated gif to pop up in a modal so that I can skin a bit... (I need an approximately 200px high modal box with 100% width, with the animated gif centered in the box).

I've tried a few modal scripts with no luck.  **Anyone have any experience or luck with the ability to basically custom skin a modal box and have an animated gif pop up over it?**

Here's what I'm using now for code, and while it's not a modal, it is working in that it will pop up the animated gif when the user clicks the submit button.  But I need to dim the background and skin the foreground, so a modal I think is where I need to go with this...

```
<!-- SPINNER CODE BEGIN -->

<div id="spinner" class="spinner" style="display:none;">
<img id="img-spinner" src="_assets/img/spin_lg.gif" alt="Loading"/>
</div>


<style type="text/css">
.spinner {
position: fixed;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
margin-left: -100px; /* half width of the spinner gif */
margin-top: -100px; /* half height of the spinner gif */
text-align:center;
z-index:1234;
overflow: hidden;
width: 200px; /* width of the spinner gif */
height: 202px; /*hight of the spinner gif +2px to fix IE8 issue */
}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#proceedForm').click(function() {
    $('#spinner').show();
});
});
</script>



<!-- SPINNER CODE END -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out jquery blockui.  It gives you full control over the look-and-feel as well as the content of the blocking message/window.

Comment: Thank you!  This looks like it will be perfect